# How do get Eclipse / m2eclipse to accept a large project set up without hanging?

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

I am trying to import Apache James Server project into Eclipse.

I had achieved to import, build and run nearly a week ago, but now i can not.

Now it starts to hang on "Importing maven projects %93"

I tried several situations

1)I have m2eclipse plugin, and have an embedded maven and use it.

Hanging on point is %93

2)Also i have a command line maven on Ubuntu, and when i set this maven(change the embedded to this) to Eclipse by "Window-Prefrences-Maven-Installations"

Hanging on %93

3)Checked out a fresh trunk and tried to import

Same result

There are lots of projects with one root pom, and every time i tried, the hanging on starts at the same sub project.

There is a post on here, so, user answers telling it is about proxy.

I controlled my proxy settings, and there is no ip address and port specified.

Moreover, i want to ask, if it is about proxy, how could i import and be able to run the project?

My Eclipse workspace log related to this situation:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 4 2012-11-09 18:31:14.132
!MESSAGE Exception loading preferences from: /james-server-queue-activemq/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: File not found: /home/gobito-merve/dev/workspace091112/james-server-queue-activemq/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.Policy.error(Policy.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.openInputStream(LocalFile.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPreferences.load(ProjectPreferences.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.getChild(EclipsePreferences.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetManager.isDerivedEncodingStoredSeparately(CharsetManager.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetManager.getPreferences(CharsetManager.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetManager.getCharsetFor(CharsetManager.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.getDefaultCharset(Project.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.core.refactoring.resource.undostates.ContainerUndoState.<init>(ContainerUndoState.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.core.refactoring.resource.undostates.ProjectUndoState.<init>(ProjectUndoState.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.core.refactoring.resource.undostates.ResourceUndoState.fromResource(ResourceUndoState.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourceChange.perform(DeleteResourceChange.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/gobito-merve/dev/workspace091112/james-server-queue-activemq/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.openInputStream(LocalFile.java:362)
    ... 25 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.filesystem 4 271 2012-11-09 18:31:14.133
!MESSAGE File not found: /home/gobito-merve/dev/workspace091112/james-server-queue-activemq/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs.
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/gobito-merve/dev/workspace091112/james-server-queue-activemq/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.openInputStream(LocalFile.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPreferences.load(ProjectPreferences.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.getChild(EclipsePreferences.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetManager.isDerivedEncodingStoredSeparately(CharsetManager.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetManager.getPreferences(CharsetManager.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.CharsetManager.getCharsetFor(CharsetManager.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.getDefaultCharset(Project.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.core.refactoring.resource.undostates.ContainerUndoState.<init>(ContainerUndoState.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.core.refactoring.resource.undostates.ProjectUndoState.<init>(ProjectUndoState.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.core.refactoring.resource.undostates.ResourceUndoState.fromResource(ResourceUndoState.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourceChange.perform(DeleteResourceChange.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: you could always just take eclipse out of the picture.  Checkout the project from a command line client, and build it with command line maven.  Then, in eclipse, "Import" as an "Existing Maven Project".

Comment: You could try with the maven-eclipse-plugin to see if it makes a difference. Try 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' and then load the generated eclipse project.

Comment: @chad thanks for reply. i did what you told successfully, saw "build success", but now how can i tell eclipse import not to build, it is still hanging on %93

Comment: Turn off the "build automatically", under project menu

Comment: Also, it seems to be a fact of life that some projects are too big . . . consider which parts of the project you really need to view from within an eclipse project.  Note, as long as you have the source somewhere, it's really not very necessary to bring all the modules into eclipse as projects; you can still step through all the code just by referencing the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had moved my eclipse's folder from one place to another and the folder had root permission by mistake. Thus when i invoke eclipse, i did it with super user and eclipse's `M2_REPO` path had changed to `/root/.m2/repository` . Now i changed the previliges and `M2_REPO` is set back to `/home/myuser/.m2/repository` and the problem has gone.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a project is just too big for Eclipse / m2eclipse to handle, at least in my experience.  Here are some tricks that I use to coax Eclipse into handling the big project.

1) Turn off the "Build Automatically" feature -- seems that this is the bit that typically breaks eclipse's back.

2) Consider turning off other m2eclipse maven functionality, like download source and javadoc; these are just slow.

3) Do the SCM checkout of your projects from the commmandline, and build them from the commandline.  I recommend having maven retrieve the source and javadocs at this time; this way you don't make eclipse do that huge chore.

4) In Eclipse, "Import Existing Maven Projects" on only the modules you need.  Consider that you don't "need" a module to be an eclipse project just to read it's source.  If you've downloaded the source during the command line build, any project that you do have in eclipse will be able to step into it's dependencies source code, both in code browsing and in debugging because eclipse knows how to find the source artifacts in your local maven repo.

And if anyone has more tips on getting the most out of m2eclipse, I'd love to see them added here.